# What happen if requestLocationUpdates() parameters minTime and minDistance are both 0

Tags: android, gps, location, tracking, location-updates

If I code:

`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,  0,  0, locationListener);`

Is that mean the location will be updated in real-time (every 0 millisecond and every 0 meter) or it won't be updated? Sorry if my question is so basic. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

> Is that mean the location will be updated in real-time

No.

> it won't be updated?

No.

It means that there is no requested limit as to how frequently you will receive updates. How frequently you *actually* receive updates will depend on circumstances. For example, the user may be in a location where GPS signals cannot be received very well.